# "Assertion Failed" on destructor

Tags: c++, stack

does anyone know whats wrong with this ?? it keeps giving me an "Assertion Failed" _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VAILD(pHead->nBlockUse) when it tries to use the detructor on a non empty stack
EDIT:MORE CODES:

```
class stack
{
private:
   struct StackNode
   {
      int x;
      int y;
      StackNode *next;  
   };

   StackNode *top;     

public:

   stack()
      {  top = NULL; }

   ~stack();

 stack::~stack()
    {
        StackNode *nodePtr,*nextNode;
            nodePtr=top;
            while (nodePtr!=NULL) 
            { 
                nextNode=nodePtr->next;
                delete nodePtr;
                nodePtr=nextNode;
            }   
    }
```

main.cpp

```
mouse_position.push(mouse_x,mouse_y);
print_stack(mouse_position);

void print_stack(stack m)
{
    int tempx=0;
    int tempy=0;
//  while(!m.isEmpty()){
//      m.pop(tempx,tempy);
    cout<<tempx<<tempy<<endl;
//  }

}
```

Comment: You mangled your memory somewhere and this isn't enough to go by. Did you write a proper copy constructor and assignment operator for `stack`?

Comment: @king: You should definitely add more code to this question, for example, what the definition of a `StackNode` is, and all the constructors/assignment/copy operators of `stack`, and which ones you are using.  Basically, a minimal code example that we can compile, that will repro your problem.

Comment: more codes added, i think these are the main ones

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal  i didnt write a copy constructor, is it needed?? how would i do so for a stack?

Comment: @kingcong: Read about the [Big Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: You don't show how to add items to the stack.  That is, how to get a non-empty stack  Since your problem is in a non-empty stack, that might be important information.

Comment: @kingcong3: That's more than likely your problem, then. Whenever you make a copy of your `stack` object, the pointers are copied. When one of the copies dies, your stack contents are freed. When the second copy dies you're attempting to free the same stack contents again, leading to your error. Your copy constructor [ought to do a deep copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) of the entire structure and its contents, and your assignment operator should invoke it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You copy your stack when passed into `print_stack` and didn't follow the rule of three [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) which results in a double deletion and your problem.

Unless you're doing this as an exercise, use `std::stack` instead - it's been tested and debugged for years.

Answer (score 4):

From the code you posted, it seems the problem is the missing copy constructor. Consider the following code:

```
stack mouse_position;
// fill mouse_position
print_stack(mouse_position);
```

When you call `print_stack`, you make a bitwise copy of `mouse_position`. When `print_stack` exits, that copy (namely `m`) is destroyed, calling delete on its `top` member, which is *exactly the same* `top` of `mouse_position`. When `mouse_position` is deleted, you're deleting its `top` twice.

Then again, there could be more bugs lurking in the code you haven't posted yet.

Answer (score 2):

Some things to look at:

1. StackNode has no destructor.
2. There are two definitions of `stack`
   destructor.
3. Missing closing brace for `class
   stack`.
4. Consider moving StackNode outside of
   the class.
5. Prefer using `std::stack` and
   `std::list`.

Edit your post to show more context for more detailed help.